# Protractor "before each" hook error with added non protractor page for login in OnPrepare()

Tags: azure, testing, protractor

I added the login authorization in OpPrepare() via ms azure:

```
//Login before run the tests
browser.driver.get(browser.baseUrl);

  element(by.css('#ms-login')).click();

  userID.sendKeys(browser.params.login.user);
  userPass.sendKeys(browser.params.login.password);
  signInButton.click();
  browser.sleep(1000);
  signInButton.click();

  // Login takes some time, so wait until it's done.
  // For the test app's login, we know it's done when it redirects to
  // index.html.
  browser.driver.wait(function () {
      return browser.driver.getCurrentUrl().then(function(url) {
          return /dashboard/.test(url);
      });
  });
```

And after it I see the time to time the same error (maybe in 40% of test runs) after authorization on 'dashboard' page.

Error code:

```
  dashboard landing page
    1) "before each" hook


  0 passing (50s)
  1 failing

  1) dashboard landing page "before each" hook:
     Error: timeout of 50000ms exceeded
```

For example spec page:

```
describe('dashboard landing page', function () {
    var dashboardPage = require('./dashboard.page.js');

    beforeEach(function () {
        browser.get('#/dashboard');
    });

    it('should have some', function () {
        expect(dashboardPage.some.count()).to.eventually.equal(5);
    });
});
```

What i'm doing wrong. please help?

Comment: Does adding `browser.ignoreSynchronization = false` before making a `browser.get()` call help?

Comment: @alecxe see the answer how I fix this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem was fixed by adding the:

`browser.waitForAngular();`

to on `onPrepare: function ()` after all login logic.

Now it works for me.